# OAuth 2.0 Client IDs для андроид приложения

Tags: android, google-cloud

Создал в console.cloud.google.com в Credentials OAuth 2.0 Client IDs Web application и  Android приложение:
[image: console.cloud.google.com]

В андроид приложении регистрируюсь со своим Google аккаунтом и получаю ошибку "Ошибка входа попробуйте ещё раз"
[image: android.app]

В myaccount.google.com в "Приложения, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту" появляется моё приложение:
[image: myaccount.google.com Приложения]
Не могу понять почему сервисы Google Play отвергают регистрацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

строку идентификатора клиента, нужно было передать методу requestIdToken в Android приложении.
Теперь регистрация в клиенте проходит без проблем.